# Why isn't the template file used?

Tags: theming

I have created a template. Its file name is exactly as specified by the file name suggestions. However, the template is not used. In the screenshot you can see the suggestion for the file name, exactly so is the template.

In the theme I have all possible templates, which all work. Only this one does not work.

Could the filename be too long? I can't get the filename before the extension shorter than 48 characters.

[image]

Comment: That usually happens if hyphens land in the template suggestion. Check that the suggestion only contains underscores instead of hyphens.

Comment: 1) Where did you place the file? 2) Is this an `/admin` path?

Comment: It's strange. I placed the template the same way as all the others which are working and didn't have hyphens in the file name. Maybe it's a problem with my form_alter code.
I now use https://www.drupal.org/project/formdazzle which gives me all working suggestions I need.